# Optaplanner Project Job Scheduling: Start successor job before predecessor job completes

Tags: scheduling, optaplanner

I am learning to use opta planner job scheduling to schedule jobs in my factory line. My particular query is

- In the book binding example provided on the Optaplanner website can the successor operation start before 100% of the predecessor job is complete? Specifically the design activity duration is 2 hours, but can its successor activities (Making cover and pages) start at 0.5 hours?
- If this is possible, what are the changes required in the input file to achieve this objective

Your help will be really appreciated!

Thanks